# Remove rows from DT1 when it present in DT2

Tags: c#, vb.net, ado.net

I have to remove rows from dt1 when the same column name value matches in dt2.

Example:
DT1:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlkJF.png)
Dt2:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oUnt.png)

when a particular **Product code** is found in DT2, I want to remove the same product codes entire row from DT1. I'm working in UiPath RPA automation tool where using invoke code activity:

I'm trying to achieve the result using linq, also tried using vb.net and c#. but facing **"collection was modified enumeration may not execute"**

for which instead of using as Datatable/datarow, modified to list and did the changes but still not getting the expected result.

let me know what i'm missing here.

```
Try

Dim temptable As New DataTable()
Dim rows_to_remove = New List(Of DataRow)
Dim row,row1 , row2 As DataRow
'rows_to_remove = dt2.Select.ToList
temptable = dt2.Clone
For Each row1 In dt1.Rows
    rows_to_remove = dt2.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(x As DataRow) Not x("PRODUCT CODE")=row1("PRODUCT CODE")) 
'For Each row2 In rows_to_remove
'If CStr(row1("PRODUCT CODE"))= CStr(row2(1))
'rows_to_remove.Add(row1)
rows_to_remove.Remove(row2)
'dt2.rows.Remove(row2)
End If
'Next row2
Next row1

dt2 = rows_to_remove.CopyToDataTable


'For Each row In rows_to_remove
'   console.WriteLine(cstr(row(1)))
'dt1.Rows.Remove(row)
'dt1.AcceptChanges()
'Next row

'values = rows_to_remove

Catch e As Exception
    Console.WriteLine (e.Message)
    
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try
Dim temptable As New DataTable()
Dim rows_to_remove As List(Of DataRow) = New List(Of DataRow)()
Dim row,row1 , row2 As DataRow
temptable = dt2.Clone



For Each row1 As DataRow In dt1.Rows
For Each row2 As DataRow In dt2.Rows
If row1("PRODUCT CODE").ToString() Is row2("PRODUCT CODE").ToString() Then
rows_to_remove.Add(row1)
End If
Next
Next



For Each row1 In dt1.Rows
For Each row2 In rows_to_remove
rows_to_remove.Remove(row2)
Next
Next

dt2 = rows_to_remove.CopyToDataTable



Catch e As Exception
Console.WriteLine (e.Message)
End Try
```